# How to accomplish distributed database replication in a disconnected environment?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mongodb, replication, database-replication

I have a PHP application running on top of Doctrine2 as the DBAL/ORM with MySQL (I can easily switch to Postgres, Mongo or any other).

I will have the same application installed in multiple geographical locations with possible unstable internet.

I need to replicate the databases in the most efficient manner.

How can I accomplish this safely?

MySQL? Postgres? Mondo? Sequoia? Any ideas on how to approach this?

FYI: ALL tables are properly indexed with globally unique UUID per records to avoid any conflicts. Transfer speed from nodes to home is very, very slow between 56kb up to 512 or 1mps in the best cases.

Thank you.

Comment: is "One read/write location and all other readonly locations" suitable for you? if so, you could use asynchronous transaction log shipping (available in all major RDBMS) - one master & multiple slaves setup.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technology silver bullet solution here. You need an application level component to actively manage this, and it is a significant, non-trivial undertaking.

That said there may be third party integration apps which can handle much of it, however I haven't experience of any such software.

Comment: Without searching too much I know there is multi-source replication, Tungsten, etc... so for sure there is something out of the box.. of course is a non-trivial undertaking...